# SocketException: java.net.SocketException: socket is closed release build

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, proguard

We are having problems with Android network requests, to be more exact receiving random

```
SocketException:
java.net.SocketException: socket is closed
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:551)
```

The request does not seem to time out, the exception is thrown very quickly and it seems to be ONlY in **release** mode, our guess is that it might be related to ProGuard.

We’re using Retrofit, Moshi, and RxAndroid for our network requests. Has anyone experienced such issues?

Our dependencies and their versions:

```
implementation ‘io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1’
implementation ‘io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9’
implementation ‘com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.5.0’
//Moshi
def moshiVersion = “1.12.0”
implementation “com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshiVersion”
kapt “com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshiVersion”
implementation “com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
implementation “com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.8.0”
//Networking
implementation ‘com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1’
implementation ‘com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.4’
implementation ‘com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0’
```

All of our models are annotated with @Keep annotations:

```
@Keep
class ModelDTO(
  @field:Json(name = “field1")
  var field1: String? = null,
  @field:Json(name = “field2”)
  var field2: List<String>? = null
)
HttpClient + Retrofit:
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .writeTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .readTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
client.retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
  .addNetworkInterceptor { chain ->
    val request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader(“Connection”, “close”).build()
    chain.proceed(request)
  }
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
  .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
  .build()
val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
retrofitBuilder.baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
retrofitBuilder.client(client)
  .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
  .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi).asLenient())
  .addCallAdapterFactory(
    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io())
  )
```

Our Gradle settings:

```
        release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After multiple attempts we fixed the issue with this:

.connectionPool(ConnectionPool(0, 1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)).protocols(listOf(
Protocol.HTTP_1_1))

This was added to OkHttpClient :) Works like a charm!

Comment: Hi, could you please expand on where you applied this change and how it fixed the issue? Thank you!

Comment: What does this piece of code does?

Answer (score 0):

You can add code below to pro-guard file:

```
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
```

But you using R8, everything included.